# NSTextField enter to trigger action

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I've been looking all over for a simple example of how to have an action (or button) be triggered when the enter key is hit in the text field.

Should I subclass the text field? Would I need to set a delegate to call the action I need? Is there a way to catch the event in my main window controller class?

If you could even just point me to the right direction that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get action after you hit enter just write an IBAction in your window controller and connect to your text field. If you want more like your method should be called when you focus on text field and leave the text field you need to set delegate([See here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTextField)).

Comment: Hi,

Thanks I've done that but how do I filter out for the enter key because when they focus or blur from the text field the action is triggered too.

THanks

Comment: To get notification when the editing is complete(either enter key or tab key is hit) the delegate class controlTextDidEndEditing method is called, there you can trigger the action. If you want your action to be triggered for only enter key then you have to either write custom formatter or customized NSTextfield class.

Comment: THanks Gudda. I actually just found out you can have it send the action only on enter as described here: http://mojomonkeycoding.com/2009/11/14/calling-an-action-when-hitting-return-in-an-nstextfield/. So thankfully no need to subclass.

Comment: The mojomonkeycoding.com website is now dead, a real shame. Eventually, I found a way to do it cleanly in code - with no subclassing - c.f. my answer below.

Comment: God Bless You! You saved my sanity

Comment: To ensure the action is only triggered when you press return, and not also when losing focus, select the NSTextField in the storyboard and change Action to Send On Enter Only in the Attributes Inspector.

Answer (score 22):

The site that is referenced in the comments to the accepted answer ... is now "SUSPENDED" by the webhost, and Google cache doesn't have the screenshot that contains the key step.

So, here's an alternative solution I found that:

1. works perfectly
2. does NOT require subclassing

For some keys (Enter, Delete, Backspace, etc), Apple does NOT invoke the normal controlTextDidEndEditing: etc methods. Instead, Apple does individual selectors for each magic key - but there's a method you can use to intercept it.

Apple's official docs here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextEditing/TextEditing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH3-SW31

...but in case that vanishes / gets moved, add this method into your delegate:

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)fieldEditor doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector
{           
    BOOL retval = NO;

    if (commandSelector == @selector(insertNewline:)) {

        retval = YES; // causes Apple to NOT fire the default enter action

        // Do your special handling of the "enter" key here

    }

    NSLog(@"Selector = %@", NSStringFromSelector( commandSelector ) );

    return retval;  
}
```

In my case, I wanted to override the backspace key too - running the app with this method, I got output saying that the selector was "deleteBackward:", so I added another if-statement in there to react to that.

Comment: FYI, if you want to catch the enter key when the NSTextView's completion pop-up is open, this method won't work because doCommandBySelector: doesn't get invoked.  Instead, you can just watch for `[[NSApp currentEvent].charactersIgnoringModifiers isEqualToString:@"\r"]` in `controlTextDidChange:`

Answer (score 2):

Just connect an IBAction of your controller class with a text field. The action should be called with you hit enter or leave the text field with Tab or Mouse.

Answer (score 1):

For the curious, here's how to implement `-controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification)obj` (if you don't care about responding to just the enter key)

AppDelegate.h:

```
// Conform to the protocol to avoid compiler warnings
@interface myClass : NSObject <NSTextFieldDelegate>

// Link up to the interface elements you want to trigger
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *myTextField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSButton *myButton;

// Create an action linked to myButton
- (IBAction)myButtonPressed:(id)sender;

// Advertise that you implement the method
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)obj;
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
@synthesize myTextField = _myTextField;
@synthesize myButton = _myButton;

// Make yourself the delegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLoading:(NSNotification *)aMessage {
    _myTextField.delegate = self;
}

// NSTextField objects send an NSNotification to a delegate if
// it implements this method:

- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)obj {
    if ([[obj object] isEqual:_textField]) {
        [self myButtonPressed:nil]; // nil = sender
    }
}
```

Worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would be to use `control + drag` to the action you've already created, so pressing `return` will also trigger the action.

Comment: Yes. In addition, you can (if your Interface Builder is not **very** old), select your NSTextField, open the Attributes Inspector and change the action to "Send on Enter Only" instead of "Send on End Editing"; this makes it easy to make the NSTextField behave correctly in for instance a URL-field for a Web-browser.