# NSTextField events and resigning first responder

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextfield, nstextview, first-responder

I want to implement an NSTextField where when I click it, it selects all the text. (to give the user easy way to delete all current text)
when I finish editing it, either by pressing enter/tab or moving the mouse outside of it's rect, I will move  the focus out of the field, and change it's alpha values to 0.5.

My Code:

H file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MoodMsgTextField : NSTextField<NSTextFieldDelegate>

@end
```

M file:

```
-(BOOL) becomeFirstResponder
{    
    NSLog(@"become first responder");

    BOOL result = [super becomeFirstResponder];
    if(result)
    {
        [self setAlphaValue:1.0];
        [self performSelector:@selector(selectText:) withObject:self afterDelay:0];
    }
    return result;
}

-(BOOL) refusesFirstResponder
{
    return NO;
}

-(BOOL) resignFirstResponder
{
    NSLog(@"resigning first responder");

    BOOL result = [super resignFirstResponder];

    NSText* fieldEditor = [self.window fieldEditor:YES forObject:self];
    [fieldEditor setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0,0)];
    [fieldEditor setNeedsDisplay:YES];

    [self setAlphaValue:0.5];

    return  result;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.delegate = self;

    [self setAlphaValue:0.5];    
    [self setBordered:YES];
    [self setWantsLayer:YES];
    self.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
    self.layer.borderColor = [[NSColor grayColor] CGColor];        
}

- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{    
    NSLog(@"the text is %@",self.stringValue);
}

- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"end editiing : the text is %@",self.stringValue);
    [self.window makeFirstResponder:nil];
}

- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [self setWantsLayer:YES];
    self.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
    self.layer.borderColor = [[NSColor grayColor] CGColor];        
}
- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [self setWantsLayer:YES];
    self.layer.borderWidth = 0;
}
```

So, I have a few problem:

**1.**

When I press inside the NSTextField (when the focus is outside) it instantly becomes and resigns first responder and I get editing end message. Why is that ?
The log I get on click is this :

```
2011-08-02 18:03:19.044 ooVoo[42415:707] become first responder
2011-08-02 18:03:19.045 ooVoo[42415:707] resigning first responder
2011-08-02 18:03:19.104 ooVoo[42415:707] end editing : the text is
```

**2.**

When I press the enter key it just selects all text inside and doesn't move the mouse focus. When I press the tab is does seem to move focus, however neither of the two causes the resignFirstResponder to get called. Why ?

**3.** 
None of the mouse event function are getting called. Do I need to to do something special for that ? I thought that since they are NSResponder's ones, I will get those for free by inheriting from NSTextField. Do I need NSTrackingInfo here as well ?

4.

Last but not least, for some reason, every couple letters, one letter seems to be bold.
I have no idea why.

I'd appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

1. I am not sure why this is happening in this case but you should read about the [Field Editor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextArchitecture/Concepts/TextFieldsAndViews.html) concept. Basically a NSTextField does not handle its own input but uses an NSTextView called the field editor to accept input.
2. You need to react to the Enter key yourself. Take a look at the [key handling documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html). Here is an [answer with an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635132/nstextfield-enter-to-trigger-action).
3. To get mouse events you can use NSTrackingArea. See the docs for [Mouse Tracking](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MouseTrackingEvents/MouseTrackingEvents.html).
4. I do not have any input on this except that sometimes text drawing can look bold when really what is happening is that the text is being drawn multiple times without erasing the background.

Comment: 1&2 seems to be related. there is some problem with the responder chain that I can't understand. Even after adding an action to the enter key and calling [self.window makeFirstResponder:nil], I still in the same text field.

Comment: Let me know if you have any idea how to fix it. I need some way to know the focus is inside the text field, but if for every becomeFirstResponder I instantly get ResignFirstResponder, I can't do that.