# Get string from NSTextView then return cursor to beginning

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nstextview

I would like to enter text in a `NSTextView` so that when I hit return the `NSTextView` clears with the cursor going back to the original position. Then the entered text displays on the screen using the `drawRect` of an `NSView`.

This what I have currently which doesn't work. Basically `self.outputString` is always the current value of `[textview string]` even though I draw and then clear. The current code below doesn't draw any string to the screen. If I remove `[textview setString:@""]` then the current text always shows what I'm writing.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor whiteColor] setFill];

    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);

    // Drawing code here.

    NSPoint point = NSMakePoint(50.0f, 700.0f);
    NSMutableDictionary *font_attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSFont *font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Futura-MediumItalic" size:35.0f];
    [font_attributes setObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    [self.outputString drawAtPoint:point withAttributes:font_attributes];
    [font_attributes release];
}


- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector {

    [self enterPressed:[textView string]];
    [textView setString:@""];


    NSRange range = { 0, 0 };
    [self.textView setSelectedRange: range];

    return YES;
}

- (void) enterPressed:(NSString*)stringEntered
{
    NSLog(@"enter pressed with string:  %@", stringEntered);

    self.outputString = stringEntered;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, set a delegate on the `NSText` object so you can take advantage of some of the delegate methods declared by the [`NSTextDelegate` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSTextDelegate).

The method you probably want to catch first is the [`textDidChange:` notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTextDelegate/textDidChange%3a), looking for when a enter is pressed.

Also, does your `drawRect` method ever get called?  If you don't know, set a breakpoint and find out.  What object is that `drawRect` associated with?  Why do `drawRect` anyways?  You could just have a nice centered `NSTextField` as an `IBOutlet` and set the font on that.

Comment: Yes, the drawRect definitely gets called. What NSText object are you referring to? This is a NSTextView. Could you clarify?

Comment: [`NSTextView` inherits from `NSText`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), so if you set a delegate on it, whatever delegate you designate will get the `textDidChange:` notification.

Comment: I've played around with this and it seems to detect when I change the text, but not when I hit return. I'm wondering if I should be using NSTextField instead. You've definitely helped, but unfortunately I'm still a bit lost.

Comment: Returns *should* throw that notification also, since a return adds a return character to the text contained in your text view.  Why weren't you using an editable NSTextField to begin with?

Comment: I found an Apple example project that only used a NSTextView. I guess that may be part of the problem? I'll try incorporating that and then see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so this definitely led me down the correct path, but this also helped me too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6016504/385559